# Checkboxes do not get checked

Tags: php, html

I am trying to retrieve the checked checkboxes whose values are stored in the database, but they are always unchecked even if they exist in the DB.
I have tried this but it did not work, although the same code with different structure works, but for framework reasons, i need to implement using this:

```
if(isset($sp['Etunimi'])&&isset($sp['Sukunimi'])){
        echo "<form method='post' action=''>";
        $comp=$this->All_Competences;
        echo"<br/>select competences for:".$sp['Etunimi'];
        $id=$sp['Id'];
        $tmp=array();
        if(isset($_POST['select_employee'])){
            $cid=$this->cids;
        }
        foreach($cid as $test)
        {
            array_push($tmp, $test['c_ID']);
        }
        for($i=0;$i<count($tmp);$i++){
        }
        echo "<table><th>valid?</th><th>Competence description</th>";

        foreach($comp as $compi){
            $checked='';
            if(in_array($compi['Competence_ID'],$tmp)){
                $checked='checked';


            }
            echo "<tr><td><input type='checkbox'".$checked."name='c[]' value='".$compi['Competence_ID']."'></td><td>".$compi['Competence_Description']."</td></tr>";

        }   
        echo "</table>";
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='action' value='selectchecked'>";
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$id."'>";
        echo "<input type='submit' value='submit checks'>";
        echo "</form>";
```

Comment: So when you do your `in_array($compi['Competence_ID'],$tmp)){` ... can you `exit($checked);` and see if it's getting set at all there? if not...pretty much know where your issue is..

Comment: try putting spaces around the `checked` keyword

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There has to be spaces between input names, so you need to add some spaces because HTML does not know to interpret it (output is: `checkedname='c[]'`):

```
if(in_array($compi['Competence_ID'],$tmp)){
    $checked = ' checked ';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 echo "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' checked='".$checked."' name='c[]' value='".$compi['Competence_ID']."'></td><td>".$compi['Competence_Description']."</td></tr>";
```

Seems you missed: `checked=".$checked`

Comment: Nope. You just need to print `checked`. The existence of the attribute is the assumption in and of its self.

Comment: He is echoing `checked`.. its `checked=` what is missing

Comment: OH god.. why :) you are right but still the line I suggested should work. As he is not putting spaces in between `name` and `type='checkbox'`

Comment: checked will work in most cases, but is not allowed in XHTML so it's better practice to use `checked="checked"`

Comment: @Mark You're worried about a WC3 Validation error on an oudated Markup System? Why would you want to move backwards rather than forwards. Sorry, I'm moving forward, not backwards. I haven't built an XHTML Transition/Strict/Frameset site in years. I don't know why *anyone* would.

Comment: Are you claiming writing html according to the xml standard is moving backward? And I'm really wondering how you were building sites before, since HTML 5 is not even considered stable yet.

Answer (score 0):

Add a space beween `checked` and `name.`

```
echo "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' checked='".$checked."' name='c[]' value='".$compi['Competence_ID']."'></td><td>".$compi['Competence_Description']."</td></tr>";
```

**OR**

```
echo "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' ".$checked." name='c[]' value='".$compi['Competence_ID']."'></td><td>".$compi['Competence_Description']."</td></tr>";
```